# jquery mobile search filterable listview

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery mobiles listview to present a searchable list to my users. Let's say I have the following three listitems:

1 This is the first searchable option.

2 This is the second searchable option. It is not first.

3 This option is a third searchable.

Now, when I type "**the**" option one and two will be displayed. That's good. If I continue, and type "**the first**", only option one will be left. I need it to display option two as well, is there any way to modify the default search to work as I want it?

In simpler terms, I want the search to do a word match, not an exact phrase match.

This is what the default search supposedly looks like:

```
    customSearch = function(text, searchString) {
        return text.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchString) === -1;
    };
```

I have a jsfiddle over here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjornstannek/xLFQ4/

Any hints welcome!

Comment: In your scenario if I enter "first second", it will give me 1st and 2nd line correct and then if I enter "first third" it should give me first and third statement correct?

Comment: Till now I have achieve this, if I enter "first second" i get 2 statement, is that what you want?

Comment: if "first third" is entered, it should display none, as no option contains BOTH "first" AND "third". For "first second" it should show second, yees, that is exactly what i want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have updated your code  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLFQ4/4/)

```
customSearch = function (text, searchString) {
    var arr = searchString.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if ($.trim(arr[i]) != "") {
            if (text.toLowerCase().indexOf($.trim(arr[i])) == -1) {
                return text;

            }
        }
    }
};
$(function () {
  $('#alist').listview('option', 'filterCallback', customSearch);
});
```

Comment: No, if I type in "the first", it will only recognize the option that contains the exact phrase "the first", whereas I want it recognize any option that contains "the" and "first".

Comment: Have updated my answer, if I enter "first third" it does not return any value, but if I enter "first  second" it return 2nd statement. let me know if you want anything else